# How can I make SCons optionally ignore a dependency with custom builders?

Tags: dependencies, scons

Here is the dependency structure of my project:

There is a single file, F, from which files A, B, and C are derived.  Everything else in the project ultimately depends on A, B, or C.

A, B, and C are built with a custom Builder like this:

```
ABCbuilder = Builder(action = build_abc)
env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'abc' : ABCbuilder,...}
env.abc([A,B,C],[F])
```

The problem is that F is unwieldy, and I'd like to have the option of not including it in the distribution, and only including A, B, and C.

How can I make it so that SCons will accept A, B, and C as the starting sources if they are present without F?  Currently if I copy A, B, and C into a new directory that does not contain F, it tries to rebuild them.

I've looked at the manual section [6.7. Ignoring Dependencies: the Ignore Function](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0/HTML/scons-user/x1275.html), but I don't see how to apply it to my code.

Answer (score 4):

You can find more detailed information about the Ignore() function in the [SCons man pages](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html). Here is the signature according to the man pages:

```
Ignore(target, dependency)
env.Ignore(target, dependency)
```

You should be able to do the following:

```
# assuming aTarget, bTarget, cTarget, and F are set accordingly

Ignore(aTarget, F)
Ignore(bTarget, F)
Ignore(cTarget, F)
```

There are several different ways to handle Command Line options in SCons, [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c2092.html#sect-command-line-options) is an overview:

The simplest way is [this](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/x2445.html), that would allow you to do the following:

```
useF = ARGUMENTS.get('includeF', 0)
if not int(useF):
    Ignore(aTarget, F)
    Ignore(bTarget, F)
    Ignore(cTarget, F)
```

And the command line would look something like this:

```
#scons includeF=1
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give it a try.  It's too bad the man pages are a bit cumbersome to search, unlike the other docs which are beautifully structured.

Comment: @L.AmberWilcox-O'Hearn Ya, I agree about searching in the man pages. The other docs lack the info found in the man pages though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought of a workaround.
I made a commandline variable that I use to determine whether the build is rooted at F.
It seems like there is probably a "SCons" way to do it that I'm missing, but I think this is fine.

```
do_abc = False
for key, value in ARGLIST:
    if key == "do_abc":
        do_abc = bool(value)

if do_abc:
    ABCbuilder = Builder(action = build_abc)
    env = Environment(BUILDERS = {'abc' : ABCbuilder,...}
    env.abc([A,B,C],[F])

else:
     env = Environment(BUILDERS = {...})
```